# Android - Make a portion of an image repeatable in android?

Tags: android, image, user-interface, imageview

I wish to achieve something similar to the following:
[image]

Notice how the image pattern to the right of the triangle repeats until it hits the edge of the screen. Also, the triangle will not actually be a triangle (i.e. the image will not be a simple shape) so please be aware of that. 
I'm quite new to Android and know that in iOS it is possible to set a portion of the image to repeat. I'm not sure if this is true also of android and if so how? If not, then what would be the recommended approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To repeat an image you may set the TileMode for this Bitmap. To move it in your case to the right you may define a layer-list drawable and give its item a left property:

tile_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/tile_start" android:gravity="left|bottom"/>
    </item>
    <item android:left="60px">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/tile" android:tileMode="repeat"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

just some layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tiled_background" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I think this would work for simpler shapes but my images are slightly more complex - The 9 patch approach is probably the way to go as Patty P mentioned above. See the comments I put under his post for more details.

Comment: I know what Draw-9 patches are ;-) but they are used to define a part which can be streched instead of repeated i'm afraid (scalable buttons with gradients or something). You may give a more specific example of what you are trying to aquire.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thanks for the approach, in fact this helps with more complicated solutions that 9 patch cant handle. For my case 9 patch suffices but for flexibility this answer is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you may want to take a look at NinePatch images http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html

Nine Patch images are "smart" in the sense they can have certain bounds that can be stretched and repeated as necessary. Here's a quick tool that can give a better idea of it, http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

Comment: Thanks, I believe you've put me in the right direction. Here's two links which describe things in good detail:
Simple overview: 
http://wiresareobsolete.com/2010/06/9-patches/
Specifics:
http://developer-dot-android.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-9-patch-image-tutorial.html